# Smart cast of map access proven with `when in`

Tags: kotlin

I’m trying to use Kotlin’s `when` block to look up an element in different maps. After confirming the element exists, the code subsequently does not smart-cast the resulting lookup in the map to not null.

Below is a minimum working example: is it possible to rework it such that `!!` is not needed?

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val string = "abc"
    val map1 = mapOf('a' to 5)
    val map2 = mapOf('b' to 4)
    when (val char = string.firstOrNull()) {
        null -> println("Nothing to find")
        in map1 -> println("Found in map1: ${map1[char]!!+1}")
        in map2 -> println("Found in map2: ${map2[char]!!-1}")
        else -> println("Unrecognised character $char")
    }
}
```

Comment: if `map1` and `map2` would both contain the same character you deliberately want to just print `Found in map1: ...` solely?

Comment: @Roland, yes, I would like to only use the first successful match.

Comment: This is a problem of the `get`-function-signature itself, which basically returns `V?`. A simple workaround (but not really shorter) is to use `getValue` instead. Or rewrite it otherwise so that you do not need to rely on `get`.

Comment: I would stick to `!!` or just use another approach without `when` ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, in Kotlin, functions can't have contracts of the form "if `f` returns `true`, then `g` doesn't return `null`." Hence, the compiler doesn't use information about definitely successful `contains` calls.

The workaround with `!!` is OK in this case because you can be sure that `get` returns not `null`. Implementation of complex patterns in `when` ([KT-186](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-186/Support-pattern-matching-with-complex-patterns)) would cover this use case by allowing declaring a variable inside `when` clauses and providing static guarantees that it's not `null`.